# Looping over lists in cf9

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfloop

Page 116 of the developer's guide says 
"Unlike the cfloop tag, CFScript for-in loops do not provide built-in support for looping over queries and lists."

Q: How do I loop over a list using the new script syntax in ColdFusion 9?

```
<cfloop list="#qry.Columnlist#" index="FieldName">
   <cfset form[FieldName] = qry[FieldName][1]>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Adam Cameron has put together a fantastic resource at https://github.com/daccfml/cfscript/blob/master/cfscript.md

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can also try the listToArray and then use the for-in construct for Arrays in CF9 as:

```
<cfscript>
aCol = listToArray (qry.ColumnList);

for( fieldName in aCol ){
    form[fieldName]  = qry[fieldName][1];
}

</cfscript>
```

Comment: Note that this works but only with Update 1 installed. The original CF9 will give an error since for-in was only allowed on struct's.

Comment: Is the intermediate variable `aCol` necessary in this example?  Wouldn't `for(fieldName in ListToArray(qry.ColumnList))` be cleaner (less scope pollution)?

Comment: Will it create additional array variable, that implicates additional memory allocation?
Does that mean that cfloop tag is more efficient than doing such stuff in cfscript?
I am asking this because I want to persuade team to use cfscript, but they giving this point as a disadvantage.

Answer (score 12):

```
<cfscript>
  var i = 0;
  var l = ListLen(qry.Columnlist);
  var FieldName = "";
  for (i = 1; i lte l; i = i + 1)  // you also can use i++ instead
  {
    FieldName = ListGetAt(qry.Columnlist, i);
    form[FieldName] = qry[FieldName][1];
  }
</cfscript>
```

---

EDIT Nicer (maybe a even little faster, for really heavy loops) version of the above:

```
<cfscript>
  var i = 0;
  var Fields = ListToArray(qry.Columnlist);
  var FieldName = "";
  var l = arrayLen(Fields);
  for (i = 1; i lte l; i = i + 1)  // you also can use i++ instead
  {
    FieldName = Fields[i];
    form[FieldName] = qry[FieldName][1];
  }
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Slightly shorter form: for (i = 1; i <= qry.RecordCount; i++) {}

Comment: @Sergii: That's the whole point - it's not about the `RecordCount`, but about the length of the `ColumnList`. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I would turn the list into an array first.  `ListGetAt()` is not efficient to be called n times in a loop.  `ArrayLen()` however should be quite fast.

```
<cfscript>
arr = ListToArray(qry.Columnlist);

for (i = 1; i <= ArrayLen(arr); i++)
{
    fieldName = arr[i];
    form[FieldName] = qry[FieldName][1];
}
</cfscript>
```

Comment: wouldn't it also be faster to call ArrayLen just once and store it in a variable?

Comment: yes it would. Just wanna keep the code segment small and neat

Comment: that makes sense ... and it's more readable using `fieldName` than `arr[i]`.

Comment: I'd probably use a `for(element in array)` loop here, Henry. You only need the index value here to get the element, so you might as well not bother with it.

Comment: @AdamCameron... it was answered back in 2010 and I doubt for-in loop for array was mature or even existed. :)

Comment: ColdFusion 9? Sure they did. And I wouldn't've suggested it if it wasn't an appropriate suggestion.

Comment: @AdamCameron see DaveBurns comment with 3 up votes on the other answer.